# How can I download daily summaries data from NOAA via the FTP link using R?

Tags: r, ftp, noaa

I would like to download daily summaries data in CSV format from all weather stations in a given US state between 01/01/1981 and 31/12/2016; however, this greatly exceeds the data limit that can be downloaded manually at once.  I would like the data to be in metric units and include the station name and geographic location.

Is it possible to download this data via FTP link using R? If so, would anyone be able to explain how to do this, or point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the links to the FTP site at NOAA? It is possible to create a list of links and the use download.file() function or you can use the system() command if you prefer a command line approach. Assuming you don't need special password privileges it should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, and sorry for the slow response. I think this is the link to the FTP: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/. I will have a look at the download.file() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ftp set up follows a standardized format (given its NOAA and longitudinal I think this is a safe assumption) you can make a list of the urls and the call download.file() using one of the many iterators like lapply or map. Here is some example code I've used to call Census LEHD data using map. Unfortunately, it is not a direct example using your data because I cannot get the link to work so you'll have to modify  a bit. But the basic logic is you find which parts of the url change, make those parts variables and provide the values you need, then call. It's relatively straightforward. In this case, the primary variables that change are the state abbreviations and year. Because I only needed two years I can just type those in directly but I use the tigris package to get the unique state abbreviations.

```
if(!require(pacman)){install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)}
p_load(tigris,purrr, dplyr)
#calls tigris "state" df to get unique state FIPS codes
us_states <- tolower(unique(fips_codes$state)[1:51])

year <- c(2004, 2014)

get_lehd <- function(states, year) {
  #grabbing all private jobs WAC
  lehd_url <- paste0("https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/", 
states,"/wac/", states,"_wac_S000_JT02_",year,".csv.gz")
  filenames <- paste0(states,"_", year,".csv.gz")
  download.file(lehd_url, dest = filenames)
}
#use possibly so if it kicks an error it keeps going
possible_get_lehd <- possibly(get_lehd, otherwise = NA)
#download the files to current wd
map(us_states, possible_get_lehd,year = 2004)
map(us_states, possible_get_lehd,year = 2014)
```